# Delete folder content apart from one subfolder with Ruby

Tags: ruby, rake, fileutils

what would be the best way of purging folder's contents apart from one subfolder?

**Example:**

input:

```
Folder_A
| Folder_B
| DoNotDeleteMe
| Folder_C
| Some_File
```

result:

```
Folder_A
| DoNotDeleteMe
```

Is there any FileUtils command that can help me with that? Wildcards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went for:

```
Dir.foreach(myPath) do |item|
  next if item == '.' or item == '..' or item == mySubDir
  FileUtils.rm_rf File.join(myPath, item)
end
```

Comment: Looks good.  If you want your code to work even if myPath does not end with a '/', then use `File.join(myPath, item)` instead of `myPath + item`